# When appending a <details> element to a div with innerHTML the div goes "down" too

Tags: html, css, innerhtml, html-tag-details

The problem is easily pictured with an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WE2pQ/).

The code goes like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="example">Hello </div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += '<details style="display: inline"><summary>World</summary>Something</details>';
```

The problem is that when I click on "World", "Something" appears but "Hello" also goes down, like this:

[image]

I would like that when you click on "World", "Hello" stays in position.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tagged this question html5 because of the details element but I'm not 100% certain the tag is appropriate. Feel free to suggest/edit and remove. Thanks!

Comment: Which browser are you using? I get it all on one line in both Safari and Firefox.

Comment: @muistooshort: google-chrome I don't think it works in many other browser. Haven't tried out though!

Comment: @muistooshort: Do you see something like this? http://i.imgur.com/9bkC7.png

Comment: Yes, that image matches what I got in Firefox and Safari. However, I got the "proper" behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `vertical-align: top` for `#example` seems to get the layout that I think you want. The HTML:

```
<div id="example">Hello <details><summary>World</summary>Something</details></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#example {
    vertical-align: top;
}
details {
    display: inline;
}
```

And, finally, the obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cJPRz/

Comment: That seem to work great! thank you! I'm just trying to figure out how to take it to my actual example a userscript...

Comment: sorry for the delay. Thank for the answer!

Comment: @Trufa: Sorry I don't have a decent explanation for why it works. The "fiddle with it until it works" technique leaves me feeling a bit uneasy.

Comment: It is very strange indeed!! I had to play with it quite more to fit my implementation but I wouldn't have got it without you leading me in the right direction. Unless I'm mistaken this is a pretty new feature HTML5 blah blah blah so there isn't overabundant reliable information about it and it's implementation. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: @Trufa: Whatever works. There might be a pseudo class for `<details>` or `<summary>`, or perhaps a `:blah-blah-blah` pseudo class for everything.